# How to draw a picture by OpenCV within Gtk in Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, gtk3

I am struggling with the integration of OpenCV with in my Python Gtk application. What I am trying to do, is to load a picture like this:

```
pic = cv2.imread("image.jpg") #pic is a numpy.ndarray
```

Afterwards, I would like to display this image using a GtkWidget. But actually I have no idea how. My first idea was to use something like GtkImage, but GtkImage can only work directly with an image file. Since my plan is to manipulate a video-stream this is not practicable.

Maybe one of you has an idea how to proceed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. So for anyone how is interested I did it like this:

```
        self.frame = Gtk.Frame()
        pic = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
        pic = cv2.resize(pic, (400,600))
        pic = np.array(pic).ravel()
        print(pic.size)
        pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(pic,GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, 600, 400, 3*600)
        Image = Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
        self.frame.add(Image)
```